# Why can't I import panda to my python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import, python-imaging-library

Every time I try to import pandas I get this error and I don't understand why, because I successfully installed it. Here it is:

```
(base) C:\Users\snin2\Documents\panda python\codigos>C:/Users/snin2/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/snin2/Documents/panda python/codigos/panda1.py"   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/snin2/Documents/panda python/codigos/panda1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\snin2\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\snin2\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

> 

Comment: Usually., that means you've loaded a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process, or vice versa.  Are you running 32-bit Python or 64-bit?  Are you sure you loaded pandas to match?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you installed right version of anaconda python.or try to  reinstall the python.

Here is the link,

if your system is 64 bit processor = https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Windows-x86_64.exe

if 32 bit = https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Windows-x86.exe